# AFNetworking Expected content type "application/xml", "text/xml", text/plain

Tags: content-type, afnetworking

I am trying to log into google reader using AfNetworking AfHttpClient but I am getting this error that I can;t seem to figure out.

Below is my subclass of AFNetworking:

```
// main url endpoints
#define GOOGLE_ACCOUNTS_BASE_URL @"https://www.google.com/accounts/"

@implementation ADPGoogleLoginClient

+ (ADPGoogleLoginClient *)sharedClient {
    static ADPGoogleLoginClient *_sharedClient = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedClient = [[ADPGoogleLoginClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL     URLWithString:GOOGLE_ACCOUNTS_BASE_URL]];
    });

    return _sharedClient;
}

- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url {
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFXMLRequestOperation class]];

    // Accept HTTP Header; see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1
    [self setDefaultHeader:@"Content-type" value:@"text/plain"];
    [self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"text/plain"];

    return self;
}

@end
```

And then I try to form a request by using the following code:

```
//set up request params
    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            @"googlereader-ios-client", @"client",
                            [keychainCredentials objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount], @"Email",
                            [keychainCredentials objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData], @"Passwd",
                            @"reader", @"service",
                            @"ipad", @"source", nil];

    //make requests
    [[ADPGoogleLoginClient sharedClient] getPath:@"ClientLogin" 
                                      parameters:params
                                         success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation , id responseObject)
     {
         //parse out token and store in keychain
         NSString* responseString = [operation responseString];  
         NSString* authToken = [[[responseString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] objectAtIndex:2] 
                                stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Auth=" withString:@""];

         keychainToken = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"GReaderToken" accessGroup:nil]; 
         [keychainToken setObject:authToken forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData]; 

         loginSuccess();

     } 
           failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) 
     {
         NSLog(@"There was an error logging into Reader - %@", [error localizedDescription]);

         loginFailure(error);
     }];
```

Im setting the default headers to

```
[self setDefaultHeader:@"Content-type" value:@"text/plain"];
    [self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"text/plain"];
```

so im not sure why it still thinks it is expecting xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Matt so I just got around to testing this. Looks like I was registering the wrong AF operation. I changed

```
[self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFXMLRequestOperation class]];
```

to

```
[self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];
```

and all was good!

Answer (score 6):

You are setting the `Content-Type` header for the request, but the error you're seeing is from the response. In order for requests to be considered "successful", the content type needs to match up with expectations (so as to avoid trying to parse a JSON response when you expected XML).

In that same error code, it should have mentioned what content type it actually got back. If it is indeed XML, add that using `AFXMLRequestOperation +addAcceptableContentTypes:`, and everything should work just fine.